# Layering two HTML component one upon another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea and a div.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />        
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSFile.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden {visibility: hidden;}           
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="txtArea" onmouseover="mouseMoved();"></textarea>
    <div id="hiddenDiv" class="hidden"></div>
</body>
```

There is onmouseover event associated with the textarea.

```
function mouseMoved() {
    var txtArea = document.getElementById("txtArea");
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("hiddenDiv");
    var newHtml = "";
    var words=txtArea.value.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        newHtml += '<span>' + words[i] + '</span> ';
    }
    hiddenDiv.innerHTML=newHtml;
}
```

Is there any way to place the `hiddenDiv` in the same layer to the `textarea`?

What I intended to do is to attach an event with the `span`s of the div such that when users move mouse over the `textarea` as well as the `div`, that event tells, what is the word under the mouse pointer. Hope I represent my problem clearly. If you want to know more, I will provide information.

Thanks and regards.

---

Edit:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />        
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSFile.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden {
            position: relative;
            /*visibility: hidden;*/
            top: -50px;
            left: 5px;
            z-index: -1;
        }           
        .txtArea {
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="txtArea" class="txtArea" onmouseover="mouseMovedOnTextBox();"></textarea>
    <div id="hiddenDiv" class="hidden"></div>
    <label id="lbl"></label>
</body>
```

And the .js:

```
function mouseMovedOnTextBox() {
    var txtArea = document.getElementById("txtArea");
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("hiddenDiv");
    var newHtml = "";
    var words=txtArea.value.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        newHtml += '<span onmouseover="mouseMovedOnSpan(\'' + words[i] +'\');">' + words[i] + '</span> ';
    }
    hiddenDiv.innerHTML=newHtml;
} 

function mouseMovedOnSpan(word) {
    document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML=word;
}
```

Comment: Check out this page: http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not use visibiliy:hidden but display:none, using the last one means that the element will not use space inside the page and you can handle easily your situation.
Good luck

Comment: thanks. I have added modified code under edit. If I don't use `visiblity: hidden` or `display: none` or `z-index: -1` the function `mouseMovedOnSpan` is working. But using any of the above three css style attribute makes that function unusable. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try to embed the div and the textarea as well into another external div and associate the event to that one that is a container of both?

Comment: I have two `onmouseover` event one is associated with `textarea` and other with `span` and the event associated with `span` takes the word as argument. Which event you are talking about to attach with external `div`?